# Expression Engine Template Exporting

Tags: templates, export, expressionengine

I have a project that was developed into a Expression Engine template. I used the Core version of EE to develop this template on my local machine. Now I need to export this template/weblog so it can be loaded onto the production server so the client can begin using EE to update their site.

The issue I am running into is how to export the templates plus the weblogs that go along with the template. This is my first time using EE so if you know how to accomplish this please explain it in detail.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot export weblogs from ExpressionEngine so the easiest way to move from a development server to a production server is to move the complete database and to move the EE files.

You will need to change a number of paths after the move. Here is a nice post migration path checklist that will help:
http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Post-Migration_Path_Checklist/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why not just export your database and copy all your files directly onto the production server?  With the information you've given, I don't see why you are trying to import each component individually when you could just tweak a couple things from the exported database/files.

If you do want to export templates, the easiest way would be to use the feature that lets you save templates as files:
http://expressionengine.com/docs/templates/flat_file_templates.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to bulk export or import templates: [DC Template manager](http://www.designchuchi.ch/index.php/blog/comments/dc-template-manager/)